# why this KvMap is not centered?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have this K-Map written with the KvMap package, but I don't know how to center it properly:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{kvmap}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{kvmap}
          \kvlist{8}{4}{\phantom{0},\phantom{0},\phantom{0},\phantom{0},\phantom{0},\phantom{0},\phantom{0},\phantom{0},\phantom{0},\phantom{0},\phantom{0},\phantom{0},\phantom{0},\phantom{0},\phantom{0},\phantom{0},X,X,X,X,X,X,X,X,\phantom{0},1,1,\phantom{0},X,X,X,\phantom{0}}{Q_2, Q_1, Q_0 ,Q_4 ,  Q_3 }
          \foreach \tikzn/\tikzi in {00/0, 10/1, 20/3, 30/2, 40/6, 50/7, 60/5, 70/4,
            01/8, 11/9, 21/11, 31/10, 41/14, 51/15, 61/13, 71/12,
            02/24, 12/25, 22/27, 32/26, 42/30, 52/31, 62/29, 72/28,
            03/16, 13/17, 23/19, 33/18, 43/22, 53/23, 63/21, 73/20
          } 
          {\node[font=\footnotesize,anchor=north east, inner sep=0.25pt] at (\tikzn.north east) {$\tikzi$};}
          \begin{scope}[on background layer]
            \fill[gray!30] (1,-2) rectangle (3,-4);
            \fill[gray!30] (5,-2) rectangle (7,-4);
          \end{scope}
        \end{kvmap}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have the same space from the left and right side of the Kmap.

Comment: For me, the image is centered. Maybe it gets visible by adding the `showframe` option to `geometry` and by placing the `kvmap` in an `\fbox`. The table-like part might seem to be shifted to the right due to the numbers and the "Q3Q4"  on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kvmap *is* centered. However, you're right into thinking that it doesn't *appear* centered, because the eye is led by the vertical rules.

You can tell TeX to back up the width of the label *Q*<sub>4</sub>*Q*<sub>3</sub> by inserting a negative space.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{kvmap}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\usepackage{showframe} % just to show the margins, remove it

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\settowidth{\dimen0}{$Q_4Q_3$}\hspace*{-\dimen0}%
\begin{kvmap}
  \kvlist{8}{4}{\phantom{0},\phantom{0},\phantom{0},\phantom{0},
                \phantom{0},\phantom{0},\phantom{0},\phantom{0},
                \phantom{0},\phantom{0},\phantom{0},\phantom{0},
                \phantom{0},\phantom{0},\phantom{0},\phantom{0},
                X,X,X,X,X,X,X,X,\phantom{0},1,1,\phantom{0},X,X,X,
                \phantom{0}}
               {Q_2, Q_1, Q_0, Q_4, Q_3}
  \foreach \tikzn/\tikzi in {
    00/0, 10/1, 20/3, 30/2, 40/6, 50/7, 60/5, 70/4,
    01/8, 11/9, 21/11, 31/10, 41/14, 51/15, 61/13, 71/12,
    02/24, 12/25, 22/27, 32/26, 42/30, 52/31, 62/29, 72/28,
    03/16, 13/17, 23/19, 33/18, 43/22, 53/23, 63/21, 73/20
  } 
  {
   \node[font=\footnotesize,anchor=north east, inner sep=0.25pt] at (\tikzn.north east) {$\tikzi$};
  }
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \fill[gray!30] (1,-2) rectangle (3,-4);
    \fill[gray!30] (5,-2) rectangle (7,-4);
  \end{scope}
\end{kvmap}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]